# Why is $n^{1.98}$ an element of $O(n^2)$?

Tags: asymptotics

Why is option "(C) $n^{1.98}$ is $O(n^2)$" the question below correct? Is it because "Big $O$" is upper bound meaning worst case, therefore $n^{1.98}$ is not worst case $n^2$ ?

How is it still $O(n^2)$? Wouldn't it have to be equal to it, not $.02$ less?

Secondly, regarding (A), how do you work out if $2^{20} n$ is $O(n^2)$?

> QUESTION: Which of the following is not O(n^2)?
>
> - (A) $2^{20} n$
> - (B) $n^3 / \sqrt{n}$ (correct answer)
> - (C) $n^{1.98}$
>
> Answer: the order of growth of option B is $n^{2.5}$ which is higher than $n^2$.

Comment: $O(g)$ is not a single function, it is a *set of functions*. The correct thing to say is "$f$ is an element of $O(g)$" and it is wrong to say "$f$ is equal to $O(g)$". However, people habitually say things like "$n^2$ s $O(n^3)$", which then confuses beginners.

Answer (score 1):

The notation $f(n)\in \mathcal{O}(g(n))$ does **not** mean that $f(n)$ is *worst case $g(n)$*.

It means that there exists $A>0$ such that for $n$ big enough, $f(n)$ is lesser or equal than $Ag(n)$.

This is clearly the case here, with $f(n) = n^{1.98}$ and $g(n) = n^2$, using $A = 1$.

Comment: can you please elaborate on you mean by  - "It means that there exists A>0 such that for n big enough, f(n) is lesser or equal than Ag(n)." what's A? and Ag(n)?

Comment: Well $A$ is a positive constant, and $Ag(n)$ is the multiplication of $A$ and $g(n)$…

Comment: Ok thanks, still trying to understand. I get f(n) is a member of O(g(n)) , so it doesn't mean the function in question is worst case for O(n^2).  Still don't get where A is comes into play like for example with option C? which n^1.98 . Maybe if I saw the workings it would make sense for n^1.98 using A you have mentioned above

Comment: Let C=1. N^1.98 < C n^2 = n^2 for all n >= 1. Where does C come from? It’s up to you to find it.